# Firefox Android Input Field Pointer

Tags: android, html, firefox

I have an input text field:

```
 <input type="text"/>
```

When I view the page with Firefox on an Android phone, if I tap on the the field to focus it I get a yellow pointer underneath. If I then tap somewhere else and de-focus (without having entered any text), the yellow pointer stays there. Is this by design or a bug, and how do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a bug. There has been a lot of work recently in the text selection and positioning code. In the latest Nightly (Fx29) and Aurora (Fx28), the yellow pointer should not appear the first time you tap into a text field. It should require a second tap. This matches the behavior of the stock browser and Chrome. Try using the latest release (Fx26) or a Nightly. You can install them side by side.

http://nightly.mozilla.org